# uploading images in winforms application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, file-upload

Does anyone know if a there is a control to allow the user to upload a image to a windows form?  Or any example code to accomplish this.

I am using win-form applications

Thanks,

Comment: Upload an image to a windows form?  That makes no sense to me.  You can download an image from the internet to a winform-- is that what you want?

Comment: @Larstech .. I have members form ..in that i need to add new member details and member image also so is there any option to click on the button like in file upload control in asp.net .... to upload the image from the system...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To allow users to select files in a Windows Forms application you should look into using the [OpenFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.aspx) class.

To use the dialog on your form you will need to find it in the toolbox in Visual Studio and drag it on to your form.

Once associated with the form you can then invoke the dialog from your code like so:

```
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
{
    string selectedFile = openFileDialog1.FileName;
}
```

You can then use the file path to perform whatever task you wish with the file.

**Note:** You can use the [FileDialog.Filter Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filter.aspx) to limit the type of file extensions (images in your case) the user can select when using the dialog.

Comment: If you are new to windows forms applications checkout the following basic tutorial which explains how to add a button and set-up a click event. [Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9w2f38k.aspx) You would need to add the open dialog invocation code to this click event.

Comment: It's better for you to start with some books on C# and Windows Forms because it's hard to start programming without this basic knowledge. Anyway you need to add event handler for the button. You can do it by hand programming or by clicking on the button twice in Windows Forms designer.

Answer (score 2):

It's note clear where you are going to upload your image. If you just want to use an image in a simple desktop application you can use OpenFileDialog to allow a user to select an image file. And then you can use this image path in you application. If you you want to upload this image to database you can read this image into memory using something like FileStream class.

Comment: Andrey gave you the answer, so upvote him if you like this:  Go here for the System.Drawing.Image control, which you can use to open, convert, and display the image once you have it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.aspx, and here for the OpenFileDialog sample: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.aspx ... You can display the Image object in a Picture control IIRC.

Comment: I do not have the code. Try to do some programming by yourself, it should be easy. And ask questions, we will try to help you.

Answer (score 2):

```
OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
open.Filter = "Image Files(*.jpeg;*.bmp;*.png;*.jpg)|*.jpeg;*.bmp;*.png;*.jpg";
if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    textBox10.Text = open.FileName;
}
cn.Open();
string image = textBox10.Text;
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(image);
FileStream fs = new FileStream(image, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
byte[] bimage = new byte[fs.Length];
fs.Read(bimage, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
fs.Close();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into tbl_products(Product_image) values(@imgdata)", cn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@imgdata", SqlDbType.Image).Value = bimage;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
cn.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private void cmdBrowser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog fileOpen = new OpenFileDialog();
            fileOpen.Title = "Open Image file";
            fileOpen.Filter = "JPG Files (*.jpg)| *.jpg";

            if (fileOpen.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                picImage.Image = Image.FromFile(fileOpen.FileName);
            }
            fileOpen.Dispose();
        }
```