upload files with a C# windows forms project to a webserver
I finished an application in c# using winform to upload an image to web server.
I searched this site and other sites to find an answer how to upload the file but no answer solved the problen..
I found code to upload file (image) but it gives me some errors then I found that I have to write a code in server side to procces the file ..
this is the code I used :
private async void BtnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //c# open file dialog with image filters
    using (OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog() { Filter = "Image Files(*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.gif; *.bmp; *.png)|*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.gif; *.bmp; *.png" })
    {
        // Get the file path from the use
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            //c# display image in picture box  
            pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(ofd.FileName);
            //c# show image file path  
            txtFileName.Text = ofd.FileName;
            //c# upload image to web server
            using (var fileStream = File.Open(ofd.FileName, FileMode.Open))
            {
                // Set the URL of the server script that handles the upload
                var client = new RestClient("https://blabla.com/Images/");
                var request = new RestRequest(Method.Post.ToString());
                using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    await fileStream.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
                    request.AddFile("file", memoryStream.ToArray(), ofd.FileName);
                    request.AlwaysMultipartFormData = true;
                    var response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request);
                    if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    {
                        dynamic json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.Content);
                        string fileName = json.fileName;
                        MessageBox.Show("Success uploading image");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Failed uploading image");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

In this code I have this error :

System.IO.IOException: 'The process cannot access the file 'D:\NATRO\IMG-20240813-WA0002.jpg' because it is being used by another process.' and did not find solition for it..

then I use this code insted :
using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(ofd.FileName))
and the result is (as MessageBox)

Failed uploading image

Also I tried File.OpenWrie File.and no result.
In this article [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7110300/uploading-images-in-winforms-application] I did not found a appropriate solution..
If I have to write a code in server side where exactly should I write it??
Hope to find any usefull answers.
Thanks and regards...

To begin with, move this: pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(ofd.FileName); after the Stream's using block. Or don't use new Bitmap(), instead Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(ofd.FileName)), true, false). Creating a Bitmap with new Bitmap() locks the file on disk

changed this line pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(ofd.FileName); with this pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(ofd.FileName)), true, false); and the result is same Failed uploading image

Failed why? Because of the same System.IO.IOException? Or something else?

No not the same System.IO.IOException it is from the if condition in this line if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK) the  StatusCode is 0

Well, the Bitmap is now loaded correctly. If the  StatusCode is 0, you have a FIN connection response: the connection has been closed

You mean that I can not reach correctly to the path? (in server side)..

Means that the connection has been gracefully closed. Could be an SSL protocol exchange failure (the TLS handshake may fail because of missing requirements: TLS version mismatch, or missing cipher-suites). Or a routing problem. I cannot test your code, so...

Ok I will try to check these options of the connection.

Are you sure you want to upload files directly to your http?
Better use ftp because http files have read-only permissions. Or you want to use a script like php to validate your credentials and process the upload.
Also your RestRequest is wrong.
use: var request = new RestRequest(Method.Post);

Thanks for replying but te code currently is var request = new RestRequest(Method.Post.ToString());

Never seen that before.
link

Thanks again , problem was resolved ,,thanks

@MUHAMMEDDÖNMEZ Could you explain how you resolved your problem?

By adding the file with ftp.. tomorrow I will share the code

@Paul Albers :
public void UploadFile(string FTPAddress, string FilePath, string FTPUserName, string FTPPassword)
{
    try
    {
        //Create FTP request
        FtpWebRequest Request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(FTPAddress + 
        "/" + Path.GetFileName(FilePath));

        Request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
        Request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(FTPUserName, FTPPassword);
        Request.UsePassive = true;
        Request.UseBinary = true;
        Request.KeepAlive = false;

        //Load the file
        FileStream Stream = File.OpenRead(FilePath);
        byte[] Buffer = new byte[Stream.Length];
        //Set file name to settings variable to use it for upload the file
        SetFtp.Default.FTPCurrentFileName = Path.GetFileName(FilePath);

        Stream.Read(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length);
        Stream.Close();

        //Upload file
        Stream ReqStream = Request.GetRequestStream();
        ReqStream.Write(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length);
        ReqStream.Close();

        //MessageBox.Show("Uploaded Successfully");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Uploaded Faild ," + Environment.NewLine + ex.Message);
    }
}

this is the code for uploading file via FTP

Yes, I think that's much easier and safer. You can do it a little bit more secured by using SFTP. There is a NuGet plugin by Renci called SSH.NET. With that plugin you can easily connect to a secure ftp.
Further: If you want to use uploading or downloading files through http, you can use for example, a php script. That php file should first validate some credentials and the uploading file. If everything is ok,, the script does his job as you programmed it. You can go much further by encrypting filenames or details. You can search for that.
But this looks ok! Glad I could help you!

And a vote will be appreciated! ;)

From the code you have provided, the http url https://blabla.com/Images/ should be a web service that accepts the file content and save it to file system of the server. The http url can not be the path where you want to upload the file. So, you need to create the web service and deploy on the server. And consume that web service in your windows form application using Rest Client.
You can search How to write web service to upload file.
Alternatively
If you want to upload files to server without creating the web service, you need to use ftp protocol. But on the server ftp path and credentials must be configured. Then you can use WebClient for ftp. You can search more about it and easily find many examples.
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUsername, ftpPassword);
    client.UploadFile("ftp://ftphosturl/fileName", WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile, localFile);
}


Thanks for replying , I think that is the correct way to upload the file ,, after configuration I will try to edit the code to be suitable with ftp protocol

@MUHAMMEDDÖNMEZ If security is a concern , you can also use SFTP protocol,  you can search more about SFTP and Its example. Please accept this as answer if it answers your question. Thank you.

Of course it was accepted thanks again it works perfectly
